# Can text animation in css be applied to images ?

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I am trying to get the shake animation to an image. 
It works with texts but not with images. Need some help here.

```
.shake:hover {
 animation-name: shake;
 }

  @keyframes shake {
   from, to {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   }

   10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
   transform: translate3d(-50px, 0, 0);
   }

   20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
   transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Are you applying it directly to the img control?? Try wrapping it in a div, then shake the div instead of the img control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```css
.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shake">
<img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with images. Your problem is that you don't define animation's duration.

Try this:

```
.shake:hover {
  animation-name: shake;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Or shorthand version:

```
.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 2s;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jeqzv3u/1)